# How do I simulate a scalable phone size in big devices like iPads

Tags: flutter, user-interface, responsive

I’m developing an app in which I want its size to work for small and big devices, but I am having trouble with the big ones. I can make use of any responsive packages or techniques but I’ve seen certain apps which make use of a simulation of a phone size, which can be scaled up or down. I want to do it in my app as well, but I can’t find the way to do it, maybe it’s with use of a a package.e

This is what I wanna achieve:[image]

Comment: This is sort of a hack to adapt phone UI to tablet, but if your phone's main view is a scrolling listl: for tablets to put your navigation in a column on the left and your phone view on the right, with like a 40/60 or 30/70 split. Navigation is anything in your drop-down menus that change your view, so if you have a hamburger menu, or a 'my account' drop-down, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I don’t wanna divide the screen or change the layout of it, I just wanna imitate the phone size in bigger devices as shown in the picture. Isn’t there any packages to do it, because there is multiple apps that do it in the exact same way.

Comment: Oh - like scale up the existing UI to fill the whole screen- There's an article here[1] that shows how to use `MediaQuery.of(context).size`, though you can also use Material's Flex-aware widgets.[2]

[1] https://medium.com/tagmalogic/widgets-sizes-relative-to-screen-size-in-flutter-using-mediaquery-3f283afc64d6 [2] https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can take the width and height by using mediaQuery
and reduce the parents height and width as much as you want

here is a code I used to make responsive

```
    class MobileView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kbackgroundcolor,
      body: Container(
        height: height,
        width: width,
         child:Container(
          height=height/3,
          width=width/3,
        child:Text())))
```

This will create something like you want
Adjust the height and width according to your device